# Problem in Addon Domain name binding with existing directory in my webspace

Tags: domains, domain-forwarding

I recently purchased a domain. At the time of purchasing I selected an option, say URL redirect, to my existing site. Further, I had entered Naming server detail. But I dint find any other option to change URL rewrite parameters under Domain Name Manager.

From the cPanel of my hosting space, I had added new domain as an addon and set a subdirectory for it. Now If I am trying to access my new domain directly, it is automatically redirecting to my old website. While if I access some inside directory, like `example.com/blog`, then I am able to access my new site.

***What have I done wrong?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't put any file in the root of my new domain. So due to some .htaccess rules, it was transferring me to my old site.